# How to join two datatables and update rows of one datatable in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

Can we join two Datatables (dt1 and dt2) and update rows of dt1 with dt2 conditionally in VB.net. can we use LINQ?
Can anyone provide me examples?

```
Public Sub MergePropLockboxAndProcesseddata()
    Dim exp As String = Nothing
    Dim Selectedrows() As DataRow = Nothing
    For Each dr As DataRow In LockBoxProperties.Rows
        exp = "HLockBoxRouting = " & DataUtil.GetString(dr.Item("PropLOckboxID"))
        Selectedrows = ProcessedData.Select(exp)
        If IsNothing(Selectedrows) = False Then
            For Each bdr As DataRow In Selectedrows
                bdr.Item("HUnappliedLease") = dr.Item("UnAppledCashLeaseCode")
                bdr.Item("HT16UnappliedLease") = dr.Item("T16TenCode")
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: To paraphrase Barak Obama: Yes you can! Now seriously, please read [ask].

Comment: @ZoharPeled:- Thanks, I have updated my question.
regarding my question, can you provide me any code samples if you have?

Comment: Can you provide a code you tried?

Comment: @Fabio: Sorry for the delayed response. Yesterday, I tried and managed the code (added in code block) for my requirement (but without using LINQ). can you provide me the same using LINQ?

Comment: Why you want to use `LINQ`, on my opinion your method is simple inough

Comment: @Fabio: No Special reason, I am a newbie and was just asked to prefer LINQ. However, I can proceed further using my code now :)

Thanks for the code formatting.